# Окно в окне сайта

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

Как сделать, чтоб в окне браузера на самом сайте вылетало окно для просмотра фотографии или текста (как Вконтакте для просмотра фотографий), а страница сайта была темной и в правом углу был крестик для закрытия страницы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Испольуйте [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), есть много возможностей настройки + открытие в модальном режиме

Comment: А объясните как пользоваться jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую воспользоваться плагином [colobox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) для jQuery.

Comment: Спасибо, не видел раньше этот плагин.

Comment: Неплохой! Возьму на заметку :)

Answer (score 1):

А может просто использовать layer...

Answer (score 0):

Я почти всегда для галерей использую [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/).